# Is there a MyPHP project much like MyPerl?

Tags: php, mysql

Here:

http://freshmeat.net/projects/myperl/

I need to enable `PHP` in `MySQL`

Comment: Great question...that project site for myperl doesn't really do a great job of selling the idea.

Comment: I need to execute a function introduced in an extension of PHP.

Comment: I didn't find the purpose to be completely clear, but check out this SO link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406/how-do-i-execute-php-that-is-stored-in-a-mysql-database

Comment: No,I need to do it in MySQL environment,or in a trigger to be exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David Sklar has made a MySQL UDF that interprets PHP code. In the last example, he runs PHP code that was stored in a database table.

See http://www.sklar.com/page/article/myphp

*Disclaimer: I haven't actually tried the module.*

Answer (score -3):

Most of the binary php distributions (Zend, ActiveState, xamp, wamp etc. etc.) come complete with mysql enabled.

The "pdo" interface (a common interface that supports several DBs much like perl's DBI) is recommend.

Comment: Did you click through the OP's link?  I don't think this is what they are asking about.  I think it's more along the lines of keeping PHP code inside of MySQL records...