# Eval Php variable with double quotes inside

Tags: php, variables, eval

EDIT: This question has been edited from the original

I have a string in a database with HTML and PHP variable's inside. Some of the HTML has double quotes as if I try to use single quotes the database escapes it by adding a quote in front of it like so: ' '.

I want to query the string and assign it to variable $x. And then use `eval("\$x = \"$x\";");` to parse the PHP variable, but it seems the double quote is ruining the eval(), and the variables are not parsing.

Is there a way to allow PHP to read the variable?

I am aware, but anyone reading this should also be aware that using eval() can be very dangerous!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can achieve it using `str_replace` if you only want to replace certain values.

Comment: @quentin I edited the question with the reason that solution did not work, it is no longer a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL string looks like this: `myVar` then php:

```
$myVar = 'hello!';
echo $$var;
```

If your SQL string looks like this: `3 + 5` then php:

```
eval($var);
```

---

In first option we use [Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

In second option we use [eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406/how-do-i-execute-php-that-is-stored-in-a-mysql-database) to evaluate code in string.